# Stack Overflow iPhone App, interest?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, iphone

Last few months I've been busy developing (yet another) iPhone application for Stack Overflow.
Now that it's almost done, I'm thinking of publishing it to the App Store.

**Question that's on my mind: Would you like to use this app?**

Some features:

- See your questions and answers (with indicators for new answers to questions you asked)
- See your current reputation and your rep history
- Browse recent, hot and featured questions
- Add interesting tags to quickly get to relevant questions (like you can on SO)
- Optional code coloring

So, would you use this (free) app?

Comment: What's the difference between yours and this one:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42337/mystacks-stack-overflow-trilogy-iphone-app-free

Comment: @snicker: Who says choice is bad?

Comment: @pho, where does he say it's bad?

Comment: @Rengers Is this based on the API (http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @Downvoter: True, but there shouldn't need to be a great difference - competition is the mother of innovation.

Comment: @snicker - Ofcourse it has a lot of similarities. However, this app's interface is tailored to the iPhone. It also has some extra features like seeing your questions and answers, so you can easily keep tabs on them.

@theHurt - No, this is currently based on the "unoffical api". I plan to use the offical one when it goes public though.

Comment: The other iphone app looks great, but crashes with every 1 in 3 messages I read, which renders it useless for the time being.

Comment: @reinier - I'm not saying my app is bug free, but I've definitely worked hard at catching any possible crashes.

Comment: @rengers @pho @dow I wasn't posing the question to imply that another app would be superfluous... I was just asking you to outline the differences between your app and that one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links in this post are all outdated, and the app this shows is most likely no longer in development. This question definitely meets the guidelines of the old "too localized" close reason.

Answer (score 2):

If I had an iPhone, I'd use it.

Only one thing, if you are using the Beta API, will you have any problems <del>if</del> when they change it?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It's currently not using that Beta API. Instead it uses the "unoffical" json api, rss feeds and a bit of scraping. However, I plan on supporting the official API when it goes public.

Comment: Great! Are you going to use my C++ wrapper? http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/34830/c-api-library

Comment: I can't visit that page because I don't have acess to the beta. It's written in Objective-C right now so a C++ wrapper would be a good candidate. I plan on looking into that in the future though.

Comment: @Rengers Send a mail to team@stackoverflow.com and request to get in the beta, they are very responsive to beta requests.

Comment: @ TheHurt - Thanks for the suggestion, I just requested access. I'm especially looking forward to implementing support for all trilogy sites.